# How to choose specific number in text using regular expression

Tags: regex

E.g. `(6:31, 23:03)`, I want to extract first number `6`, then next time I want to extract `31`, after that `23` and `03` in the end.

For `31`, I used `\d+[^:)0-9]`, but it also grabs comma.

For `03`, I used `\d+[^:,0-9]`, but this one grabs bracket.

How too grab only one number, each at the time (that means four regex total, each for one number)? This is template look of text (6:31, 23:03), only numbers change `0-99`.

Comment: Need some verification, the parts highlighted ? `6`:`31`, `23`:`03`

Comment: also 31,but i need them separetly.Its two digit max for every number

Comment: \d+ is good for choosing only first number, 6 in this case. I test it with http://www.regextester.com/15

Comment: so I can grab first number with \d+, I am clueless how to grab other 3

Comment: Need more info if it's not singular. For instance `(\d{1,2})\D*:\D*(\d{1,2})` in a global fashion.

Comment: I dont need too choose them all,only one at each time

Comment: Are you looking for a number range, like 0-31? Btw, regular expressions can match a digit defined as `\d` aka `[0-9]`. Digits can be used in a range as in a class `[4-9]`. They can also be quantified `\d{1,2}`. That's the _end_ of what regular expressions can do. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I was wondering is it possible to extract  number in particular position in templated text,That means that four regex are needed,with this one \d+ i get 6 in above example,with \d+[^:)0-9] i get 31 but with comma(its important to get just number without comma) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this leaps to mind: `\((\d+):(\d+), (\d+):(\d+)\)`. It uses four capture groups to capture each digit-cluster in one go. (You may substitute `\d+` with `\d{1,2}` to more strictly restrict digit-clusters to be between lengths 1 and 2).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aG2uW2/1

---

**Edit to address comments**

It seems a little unclear what the exact requirements are, but if I am correct to understand that you would like four regular expressions each of which would capture one digit-cluster at a time, then they would look like this:

- `\((\d+):\d+, \d+:\d+\)`
- `\(\d+:(\d+), \d+:\d+\)`
- `\(\d+:\d+, (\d+):\d+\)`
- `\(\d+:\d+, \d+:(\d+)\)`

Comment: its not needed too choose them in one go. Its needed too choose specific number in each attempt. First attempt i choose 6, 2nd I choose 31,3rd 23 and in 4th attempt 03. So i need specific regEx for each number.

Comment: @falconProger This answer perfectly addresses what you want. Can be further modified to optionally exclude : and , . What else do you want?

Comment: yeah,but I use software that has option to use regEx to extraxt info from text.So I need to extract number but  each at the time.So I dont have option to optionally exclude : and ,

Comment: @falconProger I am not sure what you mean, so I made a guess. Does the edit address your concern?